# reactjs проблема с хуком

Tags: javascript, reactjs

задача вывести `false` когда страница загружена и `true` во время загрузки страницы, пробовал разными способами но не получилось, буду рад подробным ответам, заранее спасибо

```js
const[load,setLoad]=useState(true)
//const[load,setLoad]=useState({loading:true})
   useEffect(()=>{
    window.addEventListener('load',()=>{
      setLoad(false)
       //useState({...load, loading: false})
      console.log('page was loaded '+load);
    })
  },[])
```

Comment: почему ты думаешь, что не получилось?

Comment: react приложение внедряется в уже загруженную страницу, поэтому поздновато ловить onload

Comment: @Grundy, потому что в консоле выводит true

Comment: @ЕвгенийПлатов,как думаете стоит это реализовать через redux?

Comment: сеттеры - это асинхронная операция, значение переменной не обновляется внутри текущей функции, оно обновится при следующем вызове

Comment: @Grundy, значит если поменять значение в не useeffect а потом вызвать внутри, то будит правильно?

Comment: нет. сейчас все правильно работает. Добавь `console.log('before useeffect '+load);` перед вызовом `useEffect` и посмотри сколько раз и с какими значениями он вызовется

Comment: вдобавок, не понятно зачем тебе объект в стейте, если тебе только одно значение нужно

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115357/discussion-between-vahan-muradyan-and-grundy).

Comment: оно, по моему, вообще лишнее в react приложении. loader обычно вешают на ajax запросы, но они к событию load вообще никак не относятся